# offsetHeight does not work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This code works properly on IE and Firefox but I have problem with Chrome.
BG Image doesn't load to the end.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var h = document.getElementById("right-side").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("left-side").style.height = h + "px";
});
```

tnx

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code to demonstrate how this does not work? perhaps a fiddle would help a lot. For example, what's the css applied to 'right-side'?

Comment: The problem is offsetHeight.
For example. When the page is loaded hight of pages in firefox is 3600px but in the Crome 2165px

Comment: There probably isn't an issue with offsetHeight, it might be something in chrome that isn't fully loaded yet. Try the same code on window load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IMG element may not be loaded by the time $(document).ready gets executed in Chrome. You can check [readyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it to be sure.

Comment: Why does this code work properly with Firefox and IE but only breaks in Chrome? I mean why only in chrome 0 is returned while in other browsers correct height is returned.?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a strict doctype and also you might try a css-reset.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```